# Task scheduler error- A task or folder with this name already exists

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to schedule a task using **windows task scheduler**, but I am getting such error:

```
An error has occurred for task test. Error Message: A task or folder with this name already exists.
```

I have already tried solutions like:

1. Schedule task with different names
2. Rebooting my system
3. Schedule task with different user account
4. schtasks/at command to schedule task

None of these worked for me.

Comment: What version of Windows? Have you tried Run As Administrator?

Comment: What is the commands and names you are trying to create the schedule task?